# Join two tables with pre aggregated Values results in neither grouped nor aggregated error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been trying to join tables one includes the UserId the other one contains a row for each action a user has taken. The goal is to aggregate the actions a user has taken each day.

Table 1:

```
| UserId   | date           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 13       | 2021-08-04     |
| 13       | 2021-08-05     |
| 13       | 2021-08-06     |
| 14       | 2021-08-04     |
| 14       | 2021-08-05     |
| 14       | 2021-08-06     |
| 15       | 2021-08-05     |
| 15       | 2021-08-06     |
```

Table 2:

| UserID | ActionDate | ActionVal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2021-08-04 | 2.6 |
| 13 | 2021-08-04 | 5 |
| 13 | 2021-08-05 | 15 |
| 14 | 2021-08-05 | 7 |
| 14 | 2021-08-05 | 2 |
| 14 | 2021-08-05 | 0 |
| 15 | 2021-08-05 | 13 |
| 15 | 2021-08-06 | 27 |

My query:

```
SELECT Table1.UserId,Table1.date,aggTable2.tdTotalValue, aggTable2.controlDate, aggTable2.controlUserId

FROM Table1
JOIN(
SELECT
SUM(ActionVal) tdTotalValue,
ActionDate controlDate
UserId controlUserId
FROM Table2
GROUP BY ActionDate, UserId 
) as aggTable2
ON aggTable2.controlDate = Table1.date AND Table1.UserId = aggTable2.controlUserId
GROUP BY aggTable2.controlDate,Table1.UserId
```

However, this results in returning the Error:
SELECT list expression references aggTable2.tdTotalValue which is neither grouped nor aggregated at 1:1

This is really odd to me as I have pre-aggregated the table to make sure that this doesn't occur.

Im lost and thankful for all advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is looks like you already took care of aggregation in aggTable2 subquery - you should just remove `GROUP BY aggTable2.controlDate,Table1.UserId` (in last line of your query)

If you do so, the result output will be

[image]

I used below query as a test (which gave above output)

```
SELECT 
  Table1.UserId,
  Table1.date,
  aggTable2.tdTotalValue, 
  aggTable2.controlDate, 
  aggTable2.controlUserId
FROM Table1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    SUM(ActionVal) tdTotalValue,
    ActionDate controlDate,
    UserId controlUserId
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY ActionDate, UserId 
) as aggTable2
ON aggTable2.controlDate = Table1.date 
AND Table1.UserId = aggTable2.controlUserId
```

Note: this is assumed you do not have duplicates in Table 1 - which is seems to be true based on sample data

Comment: Thanks, I have checked my data and there are no duplicates in Table 1 , Still, even without the grouping, I receive the same error. Am I missing something Big Query specific?

Comment: This just simply cannot be true, so please double check if you really removed that last group by!

Comment: I added query that I used to test against sample data in your question - check it out and let know if still issue!

Comment: You are correct, the remaining error wasnt related. Thanks for your help

Comment: sure, glad we did it :o)

Comment: consider voting up the answer if it helped! voting gives us extra motivation to answer questions :o)